# How to change CraftCMS 3 category uri name

Tags: craftcms

I have category URI named as `thank-you-page-1`. [image: thank-you-page-1]
How I can rename it to something like `my-custom-thank-you` and without change `Title` text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the slug of a category through the sidebar to the right, below the save button:

[image: Screenshot of Craft's sidebar with the slug input field highlighted]

Comment: Not noticed that it editable field. Thank you!